# ios audio unit how to get decibel directly

Tags: ios, core-audio, decibel

How can I get decibel by audio unit directly rather than calculate use formula ？

I found occur error when I use formula to get decibel. So I want to exchange method get decibel.

Comment: What specific error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The question is that I find audio unit data become abnormal from the data[512](the data size is 1024). So I don't handle these data and find the audio unit can work abnormality. Because we only use the data to calculate db.

Answer (score 1):

There is no iOS Audio Unit API that directly returns decibels.  You have to calibrate each device and microphone against a known standard, and then adjust your formula to return the calibrated results.  Then feed a suitably sized vector of frequency weighted raw audio samples from Audio Unit callback buffers to a amplitude measurement algorithm.

Comment: I use audio unit but I find that sometime collect data is abnormal , It is normal when I use audio queue(-40 - 40). I find audio unit collect data on the formula is too large.So what should I do ?